# TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable - error occurs only when script is called via another

Tags: python, unicode

I have the following code

```
#unzip
inF = gzip.GzipFile(os.path.join(homePath), 'rb')
s = inF.read()
inF.close()

outfile = homeDir[0:14]+'\\fme\\'+gridRef+".asc"
outfile = outfile.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
print 'outfile is', outfile
outF = file(outfile, 'wb')
outF.write(s)
outF.close()
```

Which is called from another script `sequence.py` and throws the following error

```
  File "gridFunction.py", line 164, in <module>
    outF = file('C:\LiDAR_Temp\\fme\SU2745.asc', 'wb')
TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable
```

If I run the scripts contained within `sequence.py` individually and in the same order, it works fine. Why am I seeing this error when I trigger the script via another, and how could I resolve the issue?

TIA

Answer (score 3):

You've probably assigned a Unicode string to file, overriding the built-in file object, so it is no longer callable.  Example:

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> file = u'abc'
>>> file('out.txt','wb')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable
```